# generating same forms with hogan templating in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, forms, loops, hogan.js

```
{#loop}
<form action="/pay" method="post">
    <input placeholder="Name" id="Person" type="text" class="validate" name="Person">
    <label for="Person">Person</label>
    <input placeholder="Ex: 20" id="Amount" type="text" class="validate" name="amount">
    <label for="Amount">Amount</label>
<input class="btn waves-effect waves-light right" type="submit" id="submit-form" tabindex="0" value="add" /> 
</form>
{/loop}
```

route side code

```
.post("/pay", (req, res) => {
pay(req.body.amount, req.body.Person)})
```

I have generated two forms by using Hogan Templating. But, When I fill both forms and submit one of them by clicking submit button. My other form that was not submitted lose the data. How do I avoid that so I do not type again and Submit?

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with hogan templating; the issue is that when you click a submit button on any HTML form, the whole page will reload by default.  Well, more specifically, the POST action will POST to the address in question (in your case /pay) which typically results in a request/response cycle that causes the browser to refresh what it has rendered.

You have a few options for solving this, if you actually want more than one form on your page, but the most common one today is to make use of Javascript to make the request to the server using XmlHttpRequest or the Fetch api (depending on what browsers you're targeting, whether you want to use polyfill, etc).

Comment: to be more clear. do i have to save the form inputs in session? So, When page reloads form data still exists. i am using node and Express. Any alternatives or Middlewares can be use to solve this will be appreciated

Comment: Then you need to update your question to better reflect your situation and goals.  I can't see what you're getting at now, as your question and comment are not saying the same thing.

Comment: Sorry, i understood it wrong. I am very new to this so after some research i am good.